# How to remove distinct values from a QuerySet and keep the pk at the same time?

Tags: django, django-orm

I am using the package `django_autocomplete_light`.

I have a simple model called Tag:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

`django_autocomplete_light` uses the following code when selecting all tags:

```
qs = Tag.objects.all()
```

The problem with this is the software I am building needs to allow duplicate tags (not my decision). That means if there are two tags "Male" and "Male", obviously there will be duplicates in the QuerySet.

I've tried to remove these duplicates by changing the query as follows:

```
qs = Tag.objects.all().distinct()
```

However I am not using PostgreSQL, so it causes an error.

Therefore I tried this workaround:

```
qs = Tag.objects.all().values_list('title', flat=True).distinct()
```

But that just causes the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

I tried changing the query to the following but it causes another error:

```
qs = Tag.objects.all().values_list('pk', 'title').distinct()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

So basically it seems like I need to keep the id value, but somehow remove the duplicate tags.

Unfortunately I can't use a raw SQL query as the QuerySet gets processed multiple times in later code.

Is there a way I can change my database query, or perhaps a way to manually remove duplicates from a QuerySet?

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for `values` instead of `values_list`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It causes the same problem unfortunately (however with a 'dict' object instead of a 'tuple' object).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround can be the following.
First, take all titles of the Tag model and put it to the `set`:

```
unique_titles = set(Tag.objects.values_list('title', flat=True))
```

Now, every tag title is unique.
Just filter out tags that has `unique_titles` like:

```
unique_tags = Tag.objects.filter(title__in=unique_titles)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately unique_tags = Tag.objects.filter(title__in=unique_titles) returns the duplicates. The result of the first query is {'strength'}, and the result of the second query is <QuerySet [<Tag: strength>, <Tag: strength>]>. (There are two strength tags in the database, obviously).

Comment: oops. my bad, didn't think about it (

Comment: Haha that's ok! In theory your solution should work, as you are querying a QuerySet. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Thanks for your help anyway.